# Make each csproj in a solution target a different C# version

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a solution that contains five C# console application projects. I would like each project to target a different version of C#.

```
MyLearningSolution.sln
    CSharp01.csproj
    CSharp02.csproj
    CSharp03.csproj
    CSharp04.csproj
    CSharp05.csproj
```

Is there a way to do this either via Visual Studio or via editing each `csproj` file?

I have tried the following searches:

- **csproj target specific C# version**, this talks about targeting a specific framework version
- **csproj choose c# version**, doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done by looking at the `<LangVersion>` element of the csproj file. Possible values:

```
<LangVersion>default</LangVersion>
<LangVersion>ISO-1</LangVersion>
<LangVersion>ISO-2</LangVersion>
<LangVersion>3</LangVersion>
<LangVersion>4</LangVersion>
<LangVersion>5</LangVersion>
```

To do it via the UI, go to Project Properties => Build => Advanced... => Language Version

Comment: I think its worth pointing out LangVersion and actually using an older compiler version are subtly different. [Eric Lippert explains it here.](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/04/what-does-the-langversion-switch-do/)

Answer (score 7):

Right click on Project, go to Properites, There under `Build` click the `Advanced..` button, there you can specify Language version.

[image]