# Build a csproj with a specific version of C#

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a csproj file that I want to build with C# 1. I haven't been able to determine how to target a specific version of the *language*. How can I edit the csproj file or use Visual Studio tooling to build with a specific language version?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859651/make-each-csproj-in-a-solution-target-a-different-c-sharp-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to the properties of your project (Right click on Project in the solution explorer it and then click on properties). Then at the tab called Build click on the Advanced button. Then a pop up with title Advanced Build Settings will appear. There is a drop down with title Language Version.

Comment: I'm looking to change the target language version not framework version.